# Is there any way I can run quickly applications from source on other distributions without installing a deb package?

Tags: application-development, quickly

Is there any way I can run quickly applications from source on other distributions without installing deb package.

What I need is to run/develop in non-debian based distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have all of the build and run-time dependencies already installed:

If you are running on a debian related system but simply don't want to install a deb I would think you can use the package_version.tar.gz by uncompressing and untarring it into a directory. Then run `debian/rules build` to make the package and `debian/rules install` to install it.

It may be possible,using the same untarred directory, to use setup.py to install a quickly python package in the typical pythonic way.

Answer (score 0):

No, You must have install .deb packages or install .tar.gz by compiling packages.